# XML nodeY.innertext returns the innextext from the node above if nodeY is empty and uses the short tag format of <nodeY/>

Tags: c#, xml

I'm reading XML files where sometimes a node innertext is empty.

I read the value like this:

```
string myString = ParentNode["nodeY"].InnerText;
```

This is fine if nodeY actually contains a value...

```
<nodeX>sometext1</nodeX>
<nodeY>sometext2</nodeY>
```

myString then contains "sometext2"

sometimes I expect nodeX to be empty...
but the XMLs I'm working with use

```
<nodeY/>
```

for a null value instead of

```
<nodeY></nodeY>
```

The problem is that if the node above has a value like...

```
<nodeX>sometext1</nodeX>
<nodeY/>
```

then for

```
string myString = ParentNode["nodeY"].InnerText;
```

myString ends up being "sometext1" where it should just contain null

How can I make sure that a node that has the short tag  for null actually returns null and not the innertext of the node above?

Comment: I'm really confused as to why you get sometext1 in that last example, are you absolutely sure?

Comment: This one was bugging me so I tried it out. There is no way your code is doing what you say. You must be reusing a variable.

Answer (score 0):

FOUND THE PROBLEM!

The above code is part of a class library that I'm building.

The class that seemed faulty was actually inheriting a variable from a base class that I also wrote.

For the a variable in the base class, the `get` method was returning the wrong variable. I made a tiny one character typo because the variable was copied from another one above with almost exactly the same name when i was first writing it.

I've just started using inheritance so that's a good lesson learned. Don't forget to check the base class!